# What's this form of rhetoric called?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, rhetoric, logic

Let's suppose my father was a good moral teacher to me. I say:

> "I learned my virtuous morals from my father."

This is a true statement, because he did teach me good morals. However the subsequent claim:

> "That is the reason why I am a moral person."

May sound suspicious. The statement may be only a partial explanation for my moral principles, ie., I also learned from my mother, siblings, friends, teachers, etc.

If it were the case that I had many moral teachers, and my father was only one among many, what do you call the statement:

> "I learned my virtuous morals from my father."

? 
It's true, but is misleading because it makes a tendentious argument towards my father being the reason. I thought of the term half-truth, and in fact it does fall into the definition of half-truth. But I don't like this term because the above statement is FULLY true. I DID learn good morals from my father, so as far as I'm concerned it is FULLY true, and I don't like the term half-truth. Neither do I like "partial-truth", because as I said it's fully true.

Also, I'm aware that the second statement is a case of making a possibly wrong conclusion from a valid premise, I'm not referring to this as in the case of syllogisms. I'm specifically asking about:

> "I learned my virtuous morals from my father."

True in every way but sounds biased towards one particular cause. Maybe it's simply a case of omission: if there are my father, mother, siblings, friends etc., and I only mention my father, it may be simply a case of omission to persuade another that my father is the reason for why I'm moral.

Are there any terms that fit this? I've already considered half-truth and affirming the consequent and these don't fit. The best one word I've thought of so far is "omission", but that just means leaving something out, doesn't seem specific enough. Can be a word or multiple, preferable if it's a recognised term in the field of logic, rhetoric, or popular culture, or can be cited from a dictionary or anywhere else for that matter.

Comment: I think it’s the word "my" that is causing the suspicious feel. Truly virtuous morals are universal. Implying ownership implies a) they’re not your standard virtuous morals and b) (for some reason) completeness.

Comment: Using "That is the reason why I am a moral person." rather than "That is a contributory factor in my being a moral person." may not please a precisionist or logician (I'm not sure about Grice), but would normally be judged pragmatically to be a paraphrase by the man in the street, and would encourage them to carry on listening to you. 'That's the main reason ...' is what I'd choose.

Comment: "I learned my virtuous morals from my father." if taken as meaning more than "I know on an intellectual level ...", as I would say most people would assume, **begs the question** (ie tacitly assumes the answer that the author now proceeds to show is a necessary entailment of that statement).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm glad that you understood the question, your comment about "contributory factor" is spot-on. I'm not saying I'd correct the man on the street, it wouldn't be conducive to good relations if we corrected every imprecision someone made. Though I would challenge someone's use of language if I perceived it as some form of demagogy or trickery for making an argument. That's why I'd like to identify what it is exactly (I'm curious).  I've read that it falls under "half-truth", but I've already explained why I don't like that term, because it's FULLY true, not half or partially.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Totally agree with the begging the question bit. There's obviously more than one problem in there, strictly speaking.

Comment: @Pam Maybe you're right, but say for example you change it to "I learned good morals from my father." You would suspect either the speaker's father was especially important", or (and this is point of my question), placing emphasis on his father in a rhetorically deceptive way. Trying to inflate his father's role for a particular motive.

Comment: @jsw29 I thought "virtuous" here was tautologous, but then realised it really isn't. If you can be raised on the morality of Saddam Hussein, then there exist bad morals, so it's not really tautologous. I could change it "good morals", that might make it less confusing, but as you said, that's not the point of the question.  About your second point, I can give this example: if you're raised on racial hatred, the indoctrination may be both a cause and reason for your animosity. That is, a cause can be a reason if that cause is both sufficient and necessary. But this is another topic really.

Comment: @jsw29, Yes, it's kind of self-obvious virtuous can mean different things. I never made any claim that "virtue" wasn't ambiguous. You first said "virtuous morals" are tautologous: "What other morals are there?". I said that there exists a distinction between good and bad morals, I never categorised which are which or that they are absolute. You then said "morals" can be a cause but not a reason, I addressed that by saying something can be both reason and cause if sufficient and necessary.  This is now a third and separate subject on the ambiguity of virtue, which I never spoke about.

Comment: The statement is rhetorically charged on a number of levels - few statment can avoid some spin by word choice but this one has a lot.  "Learned" has an intellectual and "eanred" spin, the "father" simalteously makes it sound like a "birthright" or "genetic core" at the same time.  Certainly the use of the word "virtuous" as a whole within a logically agreeable form of "certainly a person can learn things from their father" assumes that a level of learning.  "virtuous" itself, implies a bit grander character beyond being moral in knowing right and wrong... suggests noble success in it

Comment: I also agree with @EdwinAshworth that, in itself, I do not see any deceit or rhetoric in what seems like the part that bothers OP most.  I think its perfectly normal to say something like "I got my atheltic skills from my mother" or  "I got my mechanical reasoning skills from my Grandfather" and I don't see 'morals' being so vastly different than any other trait one was proud of for whatever reason in regard to "where it came from". however - other pomposity issues etc are involved in the connection and modifiers.

Comment: @Zebrafish issues with the virtuous is that the word is far more sweeping than relating to the type of morals.  I know you didn't want to dwell on it, but it's hard to read the rest without it.  Think how "my rational morals" ,  or  "my intelligent morals" or my empathetic  morals  all assert something a bit different and assert some inherent quality beyond morals .  "sound morals" would be close to rational with a bit more humility but a bit more implication of there being such thing as bad morals.  "morals" itself is an incredibly charged trait.

Comment: "I learned my good golf swing from my Father"  would have no logical fallacy to it.

Comment: @Tom22"Learned" doesn't have an "intellectual" and "earned" spin. "I learned independence from my father" doesn't imply 'earned', you don't earn an upbringing, it just happens to you.  "from my father" doesn't suggest 'intellectual' or 'birthright' it just simply means they came from your father. Learning calculus might be earned, and "noble title" might be a "birthright". And as to "virtuous morals" it's not different to "good manners". You can say manners, which most likely will be taken to mean good, but good manners isn't redundant.  Also note I never once mentioned fallacy.

Comment: @Tom22 Neither your golf example nor the one in my question is a fallacy, there may be implied premises not mentioned. That's why I used the term "style of rhetoric". Not fallacy. The answer I accepted, I did so because it was the closest to my question.

Comment: @Zebrafish Sorry to imply that you implied a fallacy. As for rhetoric, I do believe that when a word means two things, a rhetorical device is to scoop up the connotations of the other meaning even when the contextual meaning would not imply that other sense. I guess I'll disagree with you on the "learned" also earning a person gold stars for effort even if much learning is passive or from mistakes, and that calling a person virtuous without reference to morals means more than virtuous confined to morals. That sort spin is a rhetorical device and your sample sentence was thick with allusions.

Comment: @Tom22 The reason I asked this question is because someone used just this argument, implying that the one reason given was the only reason for their conclusion. That's why I wanted to know exactly where the illogic was. Regardless, I've done reading on it and discussed it and it seems people can't come to an agreement on what a fallacy or invalid argument is. Something to do with ancient Aristotelian syllogism vs mathematical logic. In other words I'm even more confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like **causal reductionism**, also known as:

- complex cause
- fallacy of the single cause
- causal oversimplification
- reduction fallacy

Essentially, this fallacy refers to arguments that focus on a single cause while ignoring other potential causes, such as attributing one's morals totally to a father.

> The fallacy occurs when an explanation of an event is assumed to be a single, simple cause when it may have had multiple causes. The cause is oversimplified, preventing a more in-depth analysis, often in order to deceive the listener as to the real causes.

- [Believing Science](http://believingscience.blogspot.com/2016/08/todays-logical-fallacy-is-reductionism.html)

An example from [*Logically Fallacious*](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/64/Causal-Reductionism) provides context, though the example is quite different from the case in the question:

> **Hank:** I ran my car off the side of the road because that damn squirrel ran in front of my car.
>
> **Officer Sam:** You don’t think it had anything to do with the fact that you were trying to text your girlfriend, and driving drunk?

Comment: I feel this is right answer. Just as I was about to say my favourite name was "fallacy of the single cause", which sounds the clearest to me, I found this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_the_single_cause  Thank you. I'll wait to see if anyone else has something to add, otherwise I think this is the correct answer.

Comment: From Wikipedia: It can be logically reduced to: " X caused Y; therefore, X was the only cause of Y" (although A,B,C...etc. also contributed to Y.).  Sounds like what I was looking for, except I was wanting to know the term for the rhetorical device, not the fallacy (if there's any distinction), but this is close enough.

Comment: Spot on. But if an intending suitor responded to 'People say I get my looks from my mother Hedy' with 'That's causal reductionism', I'd say they were woefully lacking in the pragmatics department.

Answer (score 0):

I would not call it a rhetorical device. I would call it an example of the logical fallacy [**post hoc ergo propter hoc**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_hoc_ergo_propter_hoc) (Wikipedia):

> Post hoc ergo propter hoc (Latin: "after this, therefore because of this") is a logical fallacy that states "Since event Y followed event X, event Y must have been caused by event X." It is often shortened simply to post hoc fallacy.
>
> A logical fallacy of the questionable cause variety, it is subtly different from the fallacy cum hoc ergo propter hoc ("with this, therefore because of this"), in which two events occur simultaneously or the chronological ordering is insignificant or unknown.
>
> Post hoc is a particularly tempting error because temporal sequence appears to suggest causality. The fallacy lies in a conclusion based solely on the order of events, rather than taking into account other factors potentially responsible for the result that might rule out the connection.

Comment: I have a feeling it might be a case of this. RaceYouAnytime's answer is a good one, of the many names given to this fallacy, "fallacy of the single cause" sounds right to me. I'm still thinking. Thanks, and upvoted.

Comment: This does not necessarily match the 'only a partial explanation' requirement. Y and X may be causally unrelated with this logical fallacy; not so with _causal reductionism_.